# Using 'is_authenticated' with Django 1.5 Custom User Models

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have made a custom user model for a project I am doing, and I am trying to use `is_authenticated` to allow people to access their profile and change it. However, it says there is no WSGI object. I have no idea why this could be and I would like some help!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from userstest.models import CustomUser
from userstest.admin import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

u = get_user_model()


def index(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    if request.u.is_authenticated():
        a = request.u
        form2 = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=a)
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form2': form2})
```

Comment: Could you post the traceback?

Comment: https://dpaste.de/hbRrT/

Comment: Try `request.user` instead of `request.u`.

Comment: Why not to use login_required decorator?

Comment: @xelblch, seems like the OP wants to create a user if not logged in (`form = CustomUserCreationForm()`)

Comment: @kroolik, so one view should serve both authenticated and guest users. thanks, understand logic now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, there is no "u" attribute on the request object.  Simply change `request.u` to `request.user`.

```
def index(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form2 = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, "index.html", {'form2': form2})
```